# nginx: 301 redirect to non-www, SSL urls on default_server(s)

Tags: 301-redirect, https, nginx, no-www

My goal is to have nginx primarily return a check for all requested URLs that start with `http://` and/or contain `//www.`, and 301 redirect them to the URL where `//www.` is replaced  by `//` and `http://` replaced by `https://`.

In short, all requests, if necessary, to be redirected to their non-www, SSL version, so that subsequently, all other non-default servers, serving as reverse-proxies for specific domains, will then always get https, non-www requests.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `http` server does not require a specific certificate, so all domains can be redirected to `https` non-www with a single `server` block.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 https://$domain$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.

---

The `https` servers probably require a specific certificate for each domain. To redirect from www to non-www, a specific certificate should be valid for both name variants. You should use two `server` blocks for each specific domain, the existing one and another to perform the redirect.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /path/to/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/example.com.key;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /path/to/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/example.com.key;

    ... this is the existing server block for this domain ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.